# looping through a specific parts of a nested list

Tags: r, list, loops, iteration, mapply

I am creating a function that allows me to multiply my data by random proportions, sums them thus creating a mixture of my data multiplied by this Proportion.

For example, if I have 4 data sets,  I create a Proportion of 4 random numbers that sum 100 and multiply each data set by each Proportion and sum the result.
Besides that, I want that my function iterates through my dataset and also through my proportions as to permutate through all possible combinations of Proportion dataset multiplication

A sample data set can be seen:

```
    library(LCF)
    data(stdmix)
```

My function currently stands at this Point:

```
    library(combinat)

        props <- function(corr.spec.standards = specdat, size, nprop){

  if (size < 2) stop("number must be greater than 1")

  ## create progress bar
  try(pb <- txtProgressBar(min = 1, max = nprop, style = 3), silent = TRUE)

  ## initial loop for proportions
  for (i in 1:nprop) {
    prop <- sample.int(100, size = size)
    prop <- (prop/sum(prop))
    permut <- permn(prop)

    ## permutation loop
    for (i in permut[[i]]) {

      mapply(`*`,permut, rep(specdat[i]$data$corr.spec$cor.absorption,each=length(permut)))

    }
   }
```

My Problem is that `specdat` is a nested list, which in this example is a list of 8 and that the only members to be multiplied by the Permutation are `specdat[i]data$corr.spec%cor.absorption`

Thus my Question is: How to loop through a (very) nested list only on a specific member of the list?

Comment: First, you are re-using `i` variable in nested loops which may affect scoping. Change variable in inner loop. Also, what is the current problem with your setup as it appears you are attempting to multiply that specific item in nested list?

Comment: Yeah, but then how can I make that the Iteration goes through all the "i" members of the list and multiplies them? if I remove the i in the neste loop I still get the error: Error in permut[[i]] : recursive indexing failed at level 2

Comment: Isn't it `specdat[[i]]$data$etc` with double `[[`?

Comment: I didn't mean remove it but as mentioned change it: `for (j in permut[[i]]) {`. Also, as asked, please describe what currently happens with this code and show desired result.